# Incorrect usage of UPDATE and ORDER BY. than it can be replaced by?

Tags: mysql, sql-update

```
UPDATE PlayerLeague l 
JOIN PlayerStat s ON l.player_id=s.player_id 
SET l.league_id=8 
WHERE l.league_id=2 
ORDER BY s.score 
DESC LIMIT 5
```

And I have error:

```
{ [Error: ER_WRONG_USAGE: Incorrect usage of UPDATE and ORDER BY] 
code: 'ER_WRONG_USAGE', index: 0 }
```

what this mean?

I try this:

```
UPDATE PlayerLeague l 
SET l.league_id=8 
WHERE l.player_id IN 
(SELECT player_id FROM PlayerStat s 
JOIN PlayerLeague l ON s.player_id=l.player_id 
WHERE l.league_id=2 
ORDER BY s.score 
DESC LIMIT 5)
```

but this too is wrong.

Comment: don't you think `WHERE l.league_id IN` should be `WHERE l.player_id IN`..???

Comment: Yeah. I updated the post. But that is not the point.

Comment: why you are using `order by` when updating a column value? Is there any reason or is it necessary?

Comment: I need to move the 5 players with the best score in the next leagues.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution:

```
UPDATE PlayerLeague l 
JOIN (SELECT s.player_id 
    FROM PlayerStat s 
    JOIN PlayerLeague l 
    ON s.player_id=l.player_id 
    WHERE l.league_id=2 
    ORDER BY s.score DESC LIMIT 5
) AS temp
ON l.player_id=temp.player_id
SET l.league_id=8
```

Answer (score -1):

i am not sure you intent to restrict only update few row by using LIMIT or retrieving TOP 5 playerID with high score and then updating all rows with that playerID.

if it is the first case the LIMIT should be outside the JOIN. you should check correct syntax for that. but if it is second case then here is the query.

```
    update  PlayerLeague pl
    JOIN 
    (
        select t1.player_id
        from PlayerLeague t1
        join PlayerStat t2
            on t1.player_id=t2.player_id
            and t1.league_id=2
        order by t2.score desc
        limit 5
    )ps
    ON pl.player_id=ps.player_id
    set  pl.league_id=8
```

Comment: So, it's copy of my solution